# Why does the wind force field not do anything?

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation, fire

[image]

[image]

I'm animating a rocket launch and after hours of tweaking I've come to the conclusion that the wind does nothing (it stays the same if I remove it) the exhaust comes out as a blob like this rather than a stream. And yes I've tried adjusting the wind strength.

Comment: pls provide blend file - thx